# What are pros and cons to add line-height to body { }?

Tags: css, xhtml

Is it good to add `line-height` in `body{line-height:1.5}` or it would be better if i add separately for tag by tag like `p{ line height:1em}` etc.

Edit:

body {line-height:in em} create problem with if we put image with float inside

**Edit: 24 April 2010:**

If i have to add different line heights to elements

like

```
p {line-height: 1.4}

h1 {line-height:1.6}

h2 {line-height:1.2}

ul li {line-height:1.1}
```

then shouldn't i use line height in `body {line-height:1.4}`

if `body {line-height:1.4}` and `h1 {line-height:1.6}` then what would be line height for `h1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just depends. If you put it in the body then you get to be lazy and not worry about ever doing it again, but your going to lose control because everything on the page will have the `line-height` set to 1.5. Whereas if you declared it in each tag, you gain lots of control, but will have to do more work.

Personally I would go for the tag-by-tag solution, but I'm a control freak, so...

Comment: yes it's good because universal line create problems sometimes

Comment: you don't lose control, you can still override the behaviour on the individual tags if you don't like it somewhere

Answer (score 2):

**A word of caution on putting line-height on the body tag:**

If you specify a height in percent, you would intuitively expect to enlargen / shrink all line-heights (e.g. 50% shrink to half, 200% duplicate space, 100% nothing happens).

```
body {
  line-height: 120%
}
```

**This is not the case.** For paragraphs and normal-sized text it works fine. But for headings it's a disaster, since the same line-height as for normal text gets applied... See what happens here: https://jsfiddle.net/11jgwzzu/ .

**It works, if you use for example 1.5 instead of 150%.**

With this in mind, I think it's quite okay to use something like this:

```
body {
  line-height: 1.61 // Golden Ratio
}
```

to make the entire page a bit more spacious. You can still overwrite this behaviour for some specific elements if you want to, but I often find I don't even have to overwrite it since I think `line-height: 1.61` looks pretty good everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is specifying it once in the body is less work (and overhead).

There is a definite CON: if you use a unit (like 'px') in the line-height, and you specify it on the body, it will be used like that throughout the page. This may create crazy results with fe big page titles overlapping eachother or tiny aside text getting ridiculous whitespace between lines. If you dont use a unit, and specify it nowhere else, the vertical rythm of the page becomes messy.

Read this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

> Specifying a unit (in this case, px) when setting the line-height
>   enables the value to be inherited throughout the page. If a unitless
>   line-height had been specified, the multiplier would have been
>   inherited, resulting in line-heights being rendered proportionally to
>   the text size, thus breaking the vertical rhythm.

It is common in websites to never use a unit on line-height, which is one of the reasons why the most websites look a bit messy, designwise. Just look at this page, already :-)

I would specify a unitless line-height on the body element, and use a unit-based  line-height on a designated 'content' area where you know exactly what sort of content to expect (the 'content body').

*-pike

Answer (score 0):

put it where it's appropriate

- if you want line-height: 1.5 on everything within the body, put in on the body
- if you only want line-height: 1.5 on everything in the main content area, put it on the div id="MainContent"

etc.

Comment: body {line-height:in em} create problem with if we put image inside <p>